# Is there a way to manipulate different df columns with different expressions in one line via lambda and apply?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, data-manipulation

I've been experimenting with using lambda through the .apply() method.

I noticed that you can manipulate individual values in each row, and through different expressions, as with this df and manipulation:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'credit_score': [608, 675, 502, 699, 850], 'age': [42, 41, 42, 39, 43]}, index=['i1','i2','i3','i4','i5'])

result1 = test.apply(lambda x: (x.i1 *2, x.i2 * 3))

result1
```

which outputs:

[image]

But I haven't been able to do something similar across columns instead of rows.

For example, I thought I might be able to do so with:

```
result2 = test.apply(lambda x: (x.credit_score *2, x.age * 3), axis=1)
result2
```

But this approach outputs tuples in the non-index column:

[image]

Is there a way to preserve the columns and modify the values vertically downward from the columns, instead of horizontally from rows? Basically I'm trying to understand how it might be possible to do more comprehensive calculations from a single code line—though I'd also be interested in other workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing two different operations in your example...

In the first case you are applying on the first and second rows only `lambda x: (x.i1 *2, x.i2 * 3)`. `i1` and `i2` are index of the rows

Second operation you are applying to the first and second columns (NOT rows) hence you get two rows of output

I assume you were looking for something like this?

```
credit_score age    new_column
i1  608       42    1216
i2  675       41    1350
i3  502       42    1004
i4  699       39    1398
i5  850       43    1700
```

This will give you the above ouput
`test['new_column']=test.apply(lambda x: x.credit_score *2, axis=1)`
Updated: The OP was looking for `apply` to return results to multiple columns
`test[["ex1","ex2"]] = test.apply(lambda x: [x.credit_score *2, x.age * 3], axis=1, result_type="expand")`

Comment: Thanks for the input!
The examples I gave are a bit different, but what I was trying to show with my first example was applying different expressions to different rows. I was then hoping to find a way to similarly apply different expressions, but to different columns (instead of rows).
Basically I was hoping to do in one line what I do with this clunky set of code:
ex1 = test[['age']].apply(lambda x : x *2)

ex2 = test[['credit_score']].apply(lambda x : x * 3)

final = pd.concat([ex1,ex2], axis=1)
print(final)

Comment: Ok, Can you try this `test[["ex1","ex2"]] = test.apply(lambda x: [x.credit_score *2, x.age * 3], axis=1, result_type="expand")`

Comment: Interesting suggestion! I had been overlooking result_type=expand. Your code almost gets it. If I then print test, I get the two extra 'ex1' and 'ex2' columns with the desired output. So from there I could delete the old columns and rename the new ones. But I also realized that by editing your initial df-subset to test[['credit_score', 'age']] that I wound up with only the desired column names and values....Another workaround was: output1 = test.apply(lambda x: [x.credit_score *2, x.age * 3], axis=1, result_type="expand")
output1.columns=['credit_score','age']
output1